# Key Value pair regex confirmation

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing the following data using a regular expression in C#.

I can not change the input data structure so need to know if what I am doing is correct and if there is any potential pitfalls ahead.

I am no expert in regex so would appreciate some advice.

```
string data = "[contact person]{some person name}[cellphone]{12312313123}[fax]{13131312312312321}";
string regex = @"\[(?<name>.*?)\]\{(?<value>.*?)\}";

foreach (Match s in Regex.Matches(data, regex))
    Console.WriteLine(s.Groups["name"] + " = " + s.Groups["value"]);
```

I am getting the following result:

```
contact person = some person name
cellphone = 12312313123
fax = 13131312312312321
```

Comment: so what's your issue?

Comment: If your code works and you don't have a specific problem to solve, your question might be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of the code review section:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks fine, this is just my suggestion:

```
var dic=Regex.Matches(data, regex).Cast<Match>()
             .ToDictionary(m=>m.Groups["name"].Value,m=>m.Groups["value"].Value);
```